# Creating and loading a systemd service from a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, daemon, systemd

I am working on an application that I would like to create and load a systemd service/daemon.
My minimal working example is as follows:

```
#define SYSTEM_D_UNIT_PATH "/etc/systemd/system/"
#define LOAD_DAEMON_INTO_SYSD "systemctl start test.timer && "\
    "systemctl enable test.service"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    // create the timer daemon
    std::ofstream ofs_t { SYSTEM_D_UNIT_PATH "test.timer" };
    ofs_t << "[Unit]\n" << "Description=test\n\n"
          << "[Timer]\n" << "OnBootSec=15s\n" << "OnUnitActiveSec=15min\n";

    // now create the service itself
    std::ofstream ofs_s { SYSTEM_D_UNIT_PATH "test.service" };
    ofs_s << "[Unit]\n" << "Description=test\n\n"
          << "[Service]\n" << "ExecStart=/home/gcoh/testscript\n\n"
          << "[Install]\n" << "WantedBy=multi-user.target\n";

    // finally, enable the service and start the timer
    std::system(LOAD_DAEMON_INTO_SYSD);
}
```

However, when I compile and run the error, I get

```
Failed to start test.timer: Unit test.timer is masked.
```

Even if I stop the timer, disable the service, unmask both, and then remove the respective files from `/etc/systemd/system`.

The service and timer both work as expected if I simply run

```
systemctl start test.timer && systemctl enable test.service
```

which returns

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/test.service → /etc/systemd/system/test.service.
```

(so I suspect there may be something to do with symlinks at play here)

I did some looking into this but couldn't figure out why, and I suspect the reason might be a bit subtle so I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: pause your program before your system call, and you will likely discover that both files are completely empty.

Comment: Solution: `ofs_t.close();` and `ofs_s.close()` before the system call. Doh!